How to migrate to Gradle kts prototbuf configuration in my Android application build file
I am migrating to Gradle kts in my current Andriod application.
The protobuf configuration is proving to be very challenging
the original verson for gradle is as follows:-
// Versions
def ProtoBufVersion = "3.0.0"

protobuf {
    protoc {
        if (osdetector.os == "osx") {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$ProtoBufVersion:osx-x86_64"
        } else {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$ProtoBufVersion"
        }
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            if (osdetector.os == "osx") {
                artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:$ProtoBufVersion:osx-x86_64"
            } else {
                artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:$ProtoBufVersion"
            }
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
            }
        }
    }
}

i cannot find any documentation that explains how to migrate or configure protobuf in gradle kts.
How do you configure protobuf code generation in an Android project useing gradle kts?

this works for me
// Versions
val protoBufVersion = "3.0.0"

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = if (osdetector.os == "osx") {
            "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protoBufVersion:osx-x86_64"
        } else {
            "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protoBufVersion"
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id("javalite") {
            artifact = if (osdetector.os == "osx") {
                "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:$protoBufVersion:osx-x86_64"
            } else {
                "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:$protoBufVersion"
            }
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove(getByName("java"))
            }
            task.plugins {
                id("javalite")
            }
        }
    }
} 

